# how to clear a variable to free ram memory during inference?

Tags: python, pytorch, unet-neural-network

I'm trying to train a unet on small scale images and perform inferences on large ones.
my idea was to train on my gpu and do the inference stage on cpu.
the problem is that I don't have enough ram memory.
during the forward pass, I have tried deleting a variable that I no longer need, but the memory is not being allocated again.
what am I doing wrong? 
here is my forward pass :

```
def forward(self, x):
    x1 = self.in_conv(x)
    del x
    x2 = self.down1(x1)
    x3 = self.down2(x2)
    x4 = self.down3(x3)
    x5 = self.down4(x4)
    x_n = self.up1(x5, x4)
    x_n = self.up2(x_n, x3)
    x_n = self.up3(x_n, x2)
    x_n = self.up4(x_n, x1)
    return self.out_conv(x_n)
```

the first line

```
x1 = self.in_conv(x)
```

is the one that takes most of the ram. however, I don't need x after that, and "del x" doesn't do the trick.

Comment: `del x` does not exactly remove x and free the memory. What it does is remove the reference to x in the current scope (dropping x's reference count by 1). It isn't until an object's reference count reaches 0 that the garbage collectors comes and frees the memory. Since you are passing `x` into this function, it's likely that whatever calls `forward` still holds a reference to `x`, meaning the `del x` in `forward` will not free the memory. Maybe you should calculate `x1` outside of `forward`, then `del x`, then pass `x1` to `forward`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use module gc ([garbage collector](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html))

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use torch.no_grad() during inference.

Deleting `x` like the way you have done won't free up memory as the caller presumably has a reference to the input tensor.

Comment: i have optimizer.zero_grad() in my evaluate function that calls this forward function. isn't that the same?

Comment: @yanivshe No. They are not the same. ```torch.no_grad``` informs the framework that you don't need gradients which in turn allows the framework to not allocate memory needed by autograd during backward pass. Note that you should also set your model to run in evaluation model in addition to ```no_grad```.

zero_grad() resets buffers used by the optimizer but that does not stop the framework from allocating memory needed for computing gradients